# Neutral element in monoid.

Tags: monoid

Let  $(G, *) $ be a monoid . Let $g \in G$ and $ g = g * g $. Can I assume, that $g$ must be neutral element? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and here's a more complex example:  let $\Bbb N$ be the natural numbers, i.e. $\Bbb N = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$; note I am allowing $0 \in \Bbb N$.  For any $n \in \Bbb N$, $n \ge 2$, let $M_n(\Bbb N)$ be the set of $n \times n$ 
matrices with entries taken from $\Bbb N$.  It is clear that $M_n(\Bbb N)$, with the usual operation of matrix multiplication, forms a (non-commutative) monoid with identity $I$.  However, any matrix $G$ formed by replacing at least one diagonal entry of $I$ with $0$ also satisfies $G^2 = GG = G$, but it is easy to construct examples showing no such $G$ satisfies $GA = AG = A$ for all $A \in M_n(\Bbb N)$; e.g. take $A = I - G \ne 0$ for some such $G$.  Then $AG = GA = G(I - G) = G - G^2 = 0 \ne A$.  Such $G$, though *idempotent*, are not the identity element of $M_n(\Bbb N)$.

Answer (score 15):

No, you cannot.  $\mathbb{N}^{\geq 0}$ is a monoid under multiplication, but $g=0$ is not the identity element even though it satisfies your condition.

Answer (score 7):

In fact there are monoids *all* of whose elements have this property (which is called being [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence)). For example, you can take the underlying set of any [poset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) with finite joins or finite meets ([semilattices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice)).

As an example of that example, the totally ordered set $\{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$ has joins and meets given by taking max and taking min respectively. Both of these define a monoid structure where every element is idempotent.

Comment: And another example of such, again based upon matrices, is the set of all diagonal matrices with only zeroes and ones on the diagonal!  Cheers!

Comment: @Robert: that is, of course, a special case of the above: take the poset to be the poset of subsets of a finite set!

Comment: Thanks for confirming my hunch in this matter!

Answer (score 5):

No. Take $G=\mathbb Z$ and $g=0$.

Far less drastic examples can be found in matrices.

Answer (score 3):

**Minimal counterexample**. The monoid $\{0, 1\}$ with the usual multiplication of integers. Then $0 * 0 = 0$ and $1 * 1$ but $0 \not= 1$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out already by five answers before mine, *no*. It is easy to construct the Cayley table of a finite counterexample. Let $G=\{1,2,3\}$, then
$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\ast & 1 & 2 & 3\\\hline
1 & \color{red}{1} & 2 & 3\\
2 & 2 & \color{red}{2} & 3\\
3 & 3 & 3 & \color{red}{3}\\
\end{array}$$
defines a commutative (idempotent) monoid $(G,\ast)$ where $2\ast 2=2$ and $3\ast 3=3$ but the neutral element is $1$.